# Do a BackFlip for ais523!

Tags: code-golf, grid, integer, interpreter

<sup>This challenge is a prize for [ais523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62131/ais523) for [winning](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11186/cast-your-vote-for-best-of-ppcg-2016/11191#comment37192_11191) the "[Rookie of the Year](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11191/26997)" category in "[Best of PPCG 2016](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11186/26997)". Congratulations!</sup>

---

[BackFlip](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BackFlip) is an esoteric programming language made by user [ais523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62131/ais523), who has created [well over 30 other interesting esolangs](https://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Ais523).

BackFlip is a 2D language like [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge) or [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) where the instruction pointer traverses a grid of text (the program), moving up, down, left, and right, changing direction depending on the character it's on. Critically, the grid in a BackFlip program changes as it is being traversed, a bit like [Langton's Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant).

For this challenge you may assume that a BackFlip program is always a rectangular grid of text (all lines the same length), 1×1 in size at minimum, only containing the characters `./\<>^V`. (`.` is used for visibility rather than space.) Semantically the BackFlip we'll use here is identical to the [original spec](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BackFlip#Syntax).

The instruction pointer (IP) in BackFlip always starts just left of the top-left corner of the program, heading right. There are three types of commands it can encounter:

1. `.` is a no-op. The IP continues on in the direction it was going. The no-op stays a no-op.
2. `/` and `\` are mirrors. They reflect the IP in the direction indicated by their angle, then **they change into the other type of mirror**.

   - For example, if the IP heads left into a `\`, it starts moving upward instead of left and the `\` becomes a `/`.
3. `<`, `>`, `^`, and `V` are arrows. They redirect the IP to the direction they point in, then **they change into an arrow that points in the direction the IP came from (opposite the direction the IP was moving)**.

   - For example, if the IP heads downward into `>`, it starts moving right instead of downwards and the `>` becomes a `^` because that is the direction the IP came from.

A BackFlip program terminates when the IP moves out of bounds, i.e. goes off the grid. It turns out *all* BackFlip programs eventually end because infinite loops are impossible. (You may assume this is true.)

Your goal in this challenge is to write a program or function that takes in a BackFlip program and outputs the number of moves the instruction pointer takes before the program terminates. That is, **how many steps does the IP take in the course of running a program?** This includes the initial step onto the grid and the final step off of it.

For example, the instruction pointer takes 5 steps in the trivial grid `....`:

```
 ....  <- empty 4×1 grid
012345 <- step number of the IP
```

So the output to `....` is `5`.

In the more complex 4×2 grid

```
\...
\.><
```

the IP exits the grid on its 9th step, so the output is `9`:

```
step  grid  IP position (@)
0     \...  @....
      \.><   ....

1     \...   @...
      \.><   ....

2     /...   ....
      \.><   @...

3     /...   ....
      /.><   .@..

4     /...   ....
      /.><   ..@.

5     /...   ....
      /.<<   ...@

6     /...   ....
      /.<<   ..@.

7     /...   ....
      /.><   .@..

8     /...   ....
      /.><   @...

9     /...   ....
      \.><   ....
             @
```

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

You may take input as an array of lines or matrix of characters instead of a multiline string if desired, but you must use the characters `./\<>^V` (not integer opcodes). You may use space instead of `.` if preferred. It's fine if characters like `\` need to be escaped in input. Output is always an integer more than one.

## Test Cases

```
....
5

\...
\.><
9

.
2

..
3

.
.
2

\
2

^
2

.^.
3

<.
2

\\
\/
7

>V
^<
6

>\
>/
6

\><
2

\><
\><
7

\><
\><
\><
12

\.V.
\.\<
5

\.V.
\./<
9

V./\
V./\
>./<
..\/
14

\V..
.^..
\/><
.V..
.^..
20

\.V.V.
\./.\<
.>\<..
..^.^.
31

\.V.V.V.
\./>/.\<
.>\>\<..
..^.^.^.
69

\.V.V.V.V.
\./>/>/.\<
.>\>\>\<..
..^.^.^.^.
145

\.V.V.V.V.V.V.V.V.V.V.
\./>/>/>/>/>/>/>/>/.\<
.>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\<..
..^.^.^.^.^.^.^.^.^.^.
9721
```

Comment: It's such a shame that you can't make a BackFlip solution to this...

Comment: Confused about the mirrors... does /  flips directions as left=>up and up=>left,?

Comment: @officialaimm Heading from the left into `/` will make the IP go up and heading up into `/` will make the IP go right, as if it is a ball bouncing off a wall. (But remember the `/` changes to backslash after the IP touches it.)

Comment: why '\\'<LF>'\/' is 7 instead of 6?

Comment: @tsh Because the mirrors flip direction after each use, and also you count both entering and exiting the grid.

Comment: [Looks like this is ais523's esolangs day](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115913/summing-thats-my-forte)

Comment: @ETH it changes to the direction the IP came from which is left.

Comment: Oh right, my bad. I guess I got that confused with the mirrors switching every time

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 158 bytes

```
f=(a,x=0,y=0,d=3)=>a[x]&&(c=a[x][y])?(a[x][y]=c=='.'?c:c=='/'?(d^=3,'\\'):c=='\\'?(d^=1,'/'):'v>^<'[d][d='^<v>'.search(c),0],f(a,d<3?x+d-1:x,d?y+d-2:y,d)+1):1
```

Developed independently from @tsh's answer although strikingly similar.

The mapping of directions `^<v>` to integers 0-3 is governed by the fact that `.search('^')` returns 0 since `^` is a regexp metacharacter.

Comment: I feel so soundly beaten. I was quite confused at the end there until I realized x and y were flipped compared to what I expected.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen That's a good point; maybe I should swap x with y everywhere to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>333</s> 325 bytes

EDIT:

- -8 bytes: Made `f` pointfree and merged into `b`.

`b` takes a list of `String`s and returns an `Integer`.

```hs
data C a=C{c::a->(a,C a)}
b g=[0,0]#([0,1],map(maybe(C$m 1)C.(`lookup`zip"./^>V<"[n,m(-1),a[-1,0],a[0,1],a[1,0],a[0,-1]]))<$>g)
[y,x]#(d,g)|g&y||g!!0&x=1|n@([f,e],_)<-(($d).c)?x?y$g=1+[y+f,x+e]#n
l&i=i<0||i>=length l
(f?i)l|(p,a:r)<-splitAt i l=(p++).(:r)<$>f a
n d=(d,C n)
a v d=(v,C$a$(0-)<$>d)
m s[d,e]=([s*e,s*d],C$m(-s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#bU/LbsIwELz7KwxYyEsck1xRHFrlH7g4oTjkgVXHRCSlSZt@OzU99IDQHEazmtmdbZS2Qtu@vKhjT7rT@ZPn3GhbdrdC9QonWInk@7jZKD@mijkJPyjHtZABC7IFdRRmrFEtbdSYlzQhDQ4h4fRgzuf3j/bwpds5X@/jXTSXljXUD4Ep6Ycu7fgvreS/8sMsA4hIXAOSIxvchYLVMNXLcZrq2SxYDiKc7AuVFSsz9gaRTykpgB9hO2xHUovQk6NXscErs4VFZqmFjoJp0rEwpa37EzaIVlsNZqItU5uL29C1RvevPdbYCNp6HnB6n5O4wgpZXAjXIcEWkMLXu7qyhChCA//uKQA1uJOFqyOo7FYl61ZF5hzu1Q7gdkv57glQytfxA3gaIR6nj4g4R5zvnwD9Ag)

## How it works

- `C a` is a data type used because Haskell won't allow a type to be recursive without declaring it explicitly. `C` is also a wrapping constructor and `c` is its corresponding unwrapping function. It is only used with `a=[Int]`.

  - The type `C [Int]` represents a cell command, as a function that takes a direction (`[Int]`) argument, and returns a pair of a new direction, and a new `C [Int]` value.
- `b` is the main function. It converts each character into a `C` value, then it calls `#`.

  - `g` is the grid as a list of strings.
  - Since `\`  needs to be escaped and so is the longest character to mention, its result is instead used as the default value for the list lookup.
- `#` runs the main simulation, checking bounds with `&` and generating new grids with `?`. `[y,x]` is the current position, `d` the current direction, and `g` the current grid. `[f,e]` is the next direction, and `n` is a pair of it and the next grid.
- `l&i` checks if the index `i` is out of bounds for the list `l`. (It returns `True` for out of bounds, since that avoids a dummy guard condition in `#`.)
- When `f(l!!i)==(d,x)`, `(f?i)l==(d,m)` where `m` is the list `l` with the `i`th element replaced with `x`.

  - Technically `(?i)` is a more general lens, focusing on the i'th element of a list, in this case used with the `(,) [Int]` functor instance.
- `n` is the function representing a dot.
- `a v` is a function representing an arrow in direction `v`.
- `m s` is a function representing a mirror; `s==1` for `\\` and `s==-1` for `/`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 286 bytes

[f() takes input in the form of `{(0,0):'/',(0,1):'.'}` so I have also written a function g() for converting an array of lines to that form]

```python
def f(r):
 x=y=0;d='>';s=1
 while 1:
  try:c=r[y,x];m='>^<V'.find(d)
  except:break
  if(c=="\\"):d='V<^>'[m];r[y,x]="/"
  elif(c=="/"):d='^>V<'[m];r[y,x]="\\"
  elif(c!="."):r[y,x]='<V>^'[m];d=c
  x+=1if(d=='>')else-1if(d=='<')else 0;y+=1if(d=='V')else-1if(d=='^')else 0;s+=1
 return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#bZBNboMwEIX3nMJlY6OkhmzB42OwMSCl2KROCY0MVUFVz07H5Kclqt5mxu@bZ3u0aciBDVEaEAdf3wFp3h2xxHbE7buDYa3p0PX24hwfHJWUaDplt8cSBmVLdSwxyQwfDrlZY3rDnB8fYYIk00AlzXrYBeTz1baG7Hzy4Ka0Bqem7VhmJ0QqkVPe2E4zHaFvxtqch/TFmf0btrZhNUBYFGGUYmAuKknVqcwuARDGoZ9pr1h8oSqZixWF43fsCUIe@n8sFhW5rBZWQ43MuIEdUhr84yPT9ub51otLT5Js@oXyB6i6Q/3G//y6nn4@O9sNrGEHpmjB80V0i2UsY14ILLksZCG4P@W8WkRx41Hw3@hat6C1/sSutb5kreXK@Qc)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 172 bytes

```
f=(a,d=3,x=0,y=0,n=1)=>(p=a[y]||[],q=p[x])?(p[x]=~(t='^<V>'.indexOf(q))?'^<V>'[d^2]:q=='/'?(t=3-d,'\\'):q=='\\'?(t=d^1,'/'):(t=d,q),f(a,t,x+(t&1&&t-2),y+(~t&1&&t-1),n+1)):n
```

But i cannot test last testcase since i got stack overflow on my machine. (should work if there is a machine with larger ram)

We use a number for direction:

- 0: ^
- 1: <
- 2: V
- 3: >

Let `d` be the direction number...

- if we meet a '/', we need d = 3 - d;
- if we meet a '\' we need d = d ^ 1;
- if we meet a '^<V>' we need d = '^<V>'.indexOf(note)

Let `(x, y)` be current position, the next position is: `x+(t&1&&t-2)`, `y+(~t&1&&t-1)`

**Note:**

The function takes one paramter with the following format:

```
[ [ '\\', '.', 'V', '.', 'V', '.', 'V', '.', 'V', '.' ],
  [ '\\', '.', '/', '>', '/', '>', '/', '.', '\\', '<' ],
  [ '.', '>', '\\', '>', '\\', '>', '\\', '<', '.', '.' ],
  [ '.', '.', '^', '.', '^', '.', '^', '.', '^', '.' ] ]
```

**Test it here**

```js
f=(a,d=3,x=0,y=0,n=1)=>(p=a[y]||[],q=p[x])?(p[x]=~(t='^<V>'.indexOf(q))?'^<V>'[d^2]:q=='/'?(t=3-d,'\\'):q=='\\'?(t=d^1,'/'):(t=d,q),f(a,t,x+(t&1&&t-2),y+(~t&1&&t-1),n+1)):n

    ;k=x=>x.split('\n').map(t=>t.split(''));
```

```html
<textarea id=v>\.V.V.V.V.
\./>/>/.\<
.>\>\>\<..
..^.^.^.^.</textarea><br/><button onclick="r.textContent=f(k(v.value))">Solve</button>
<p>Result: <output id=r></output></p>
```

Comment: Just to document, I'm getting `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` with 16GB RAM.

Comment: @ZebMcCorkle aha, just find out that "use strict" and some `var` declaration make it pass the last testcase (js interpreter do tail call optimize in strict mode)

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>232</s> 221 bytes

```c
d,n,t,m[4]={1,-1};char*w="><^V/\\.",*P;main(o,v)char**v;{for(P=v[1],m[2]=-(m[3]=strchr(P,10)-P+1);P>=v[1]&&P<strchr(v[1],0)&&*P^10;++n)*P=w[((o=d,t=strchr(w,*P)-w)<4)?d=t,o^1:(t<6)?d^=t-2,9-t:6],P+=m[d];printf("%d",n+1);}
```

Takes input in first argument, prints result. Requires that input contains at least 1 newline (so if there's only 1 row, it must end with a newline)

Example usage:

```sh
./backflip '....
';
```

Breakdown:

```c
d,                                          // Direction
n,                                          // Step counter
t,
m[4]={1,-1};                                // Movement offsets
char*w="><^V/\\.",                          // Command lookup
*P;                                         // Cursor location
main(o,v)char**v;{
    for(P=v[1],                             // Begin at 0,0
        m[2]=-(m[3]=strchr(P,10)-P+1);      // Find width of grid
        P>=v[1]&&P<strchr(v[1],0)&&*P^10;   // While inside grid:
        ++n)                                //  Increment step
        *P=w[                               //  Update the current cell
            ((o=d,t=strchr(w,*P)-w)         //  (store current direction & command)
              <4)?d=t,o^1:                  //   If <>^V, write backflip & set dir
            (t<6)?d^=t-2,9-t:               //   If / or \, write flip & bounce
            6],                             //   If ., write unchanged & continue
        P+=m[d];                            //  Move
    printf("%d",n+1);                       // Print result
}
```

Comment: [206 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY7NisIwFEb3PkbBkp@bTKMiaHLrK2Q1mzYFacaxi6ZDCemA@OyZirP6FgfO@Xrx3fc5ewgQYWwODh8KhHrq/n6d2YJFbbrPj7aVBTCrx@sQyASJDiEylvTjNs1kbHYOxTp7h0PwX7/EIuM8gaqosFxRbWtkqbTmTVmCipYls52qNOeBMotLQyb0EP8FyxqjYqHmcPEYYerUOZrjxXcYxQ5OIp6PDizHsfFO/8zrmxsptr6A8Mo9c86tlHLTytr8AQ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")